# Finding the Complicated Posterior Probability Distribution of $θ$

Tags: bayesian, posterior, bayes, conjugate-prior

Suppose, we are given a likelihood function, $f(x|θ)$ corresponding to a shifted-exponential distribution and the prior distribution on the parameter $θ$ is a standard Cauchy distribution.

Now I am having problems while deriving the posterior distribution, which is given by its density $$p(θ|x) ∝ f(x|θ)g(θ)$$ where $g(θ)$ is the prior distribution density.

Here, 
\begin{align*}
f(x|θ) &= e^{-(x-θ)}\qquad x > θ\\
g(θ) &= \frac {1}{π}\frac {1}{1+θ^{2}}\quad -∞ < θ < ∞
\end{align*}

Hence, $$p(θ|x) = \frac {e^{-(x-θ)}\frac{1}{π}\frac {1}{1+θ^{2}}\mathbb{I}_{\theta\le x}} {\int_{-\infty}^x e^{-(x-θ)}\frac{1}{π}\frac {1}{1+θ^{2}} dθ}$$

This turns out to be, $$p(θ|x) = \frac {e^{θ}\frac {1}{1+θ^{2}}\mathbb{I}_{\theta\le x}} {\int_{-\infty}^x e^{θ} \frac {1}{1+θ^{2}} dθ}$$

How will I proceed now ? Can anyone help me further with the form of the posterior distribution ?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your derivation. The posterior is non-standard, that's all!

Comment: Checking on Wolfram Alpha, it does not seem the denominator is a particularly well-known special function!

Comment: Yes sir, I did check that :(  @Xi'an

So what shall I do ? How will I arrive at the solution ? :(

Comment: and thank you, Sir, for editing my post ! :) @Xi'an

Comment: MCMC is a framework allowing you to sample from non normalized distributions (the most common use case is posteriors without analytic form) for computing expectations.  Many good packages for this type of problem exist such as PyMC for Python.

Comment: Thank you, Sir, for your suggestion ! 
But the main problem is, Sir, that it is a theoretical problem. :(
That is precisely the reason why I am asking for the solution, the theoretical one..!

If it had been a practical assignment problem, I might have been able to do it..